# How do I create the function that assigns a key to start a timer

Tags: vb.net, keyboard-shortcuts

(I saw that on youtube)   Basically there is a textbox and under a button. How can I make sure that when I insert a letter and then press the button the letter when pressed to start the timer? Basically you need to assign a key to a certain function. 
I searched on youtube but I didn't find anything

Comment: There's no such thing as assigning a key to a function. If you want to test that the `TextBox` contains a certain character(s) when the user clicks that `Button` then you need to handle the `Click` event of the `Button` and add the appropriate code.  If that's not what you mean then you need to try again to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of what you want. Just as importantly though, you need to show that you've made some effort. Questions that read "this is what I want, tell me how" are off-topic here at SO.

Comment: I'm assuming here that you have several timers and you want one of them to start depending on which letter is in the text box?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do something like this when you handle the [KeyDown Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here is a example how you can handle this:

```
'function get triggered when a Key got pressed
Private Sub EnterEvent(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown  
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        MsgBox("Congrats! You pressed Enter ;)")
    End If
End Sub
```

I hope this will bring you on the right track! Happy coding :)